# Hibernate PostUpdateEvent never being called

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistent

I'm trying to implement some event listeners in order to log the history of some entities in my java EE application. I followed all steps suggested by https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-event-listeners/ but couldn't manage it to work.

**Update listener:**

```java
public class HistoryUpdateEventListener implements PostUpdateEventListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger( HistoryUpdateEventListener.class );
    
    public static final HistoryUpdateEventListener INSTANCE = new HistoryUpdateEventListener();

    @Override
    public void onPostUpdate( PostUpdateEvent event ) {
        // post update logic
    }

    @Override
    public boolean requiresPostCommitHanding(EntityPersister persister) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Listener integrator:**

```java
public class HistoryEventListenerIntegrator implements Integrator {

    @Override
    public void integrate( Metadata metadata, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry ) {
        final EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry = serviceRegistry.getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        
        eventListenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_UPDATE, HistoryUpdateEventListener.INSTANCE);
    }

    @Override
    public void disintegrate( SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry ) {
        
    }

}
```

**Persistence xml**

```xml
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.integrator_provider" value="com.app.HistoryEventListenerIntegrator" />
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2dll.extra_physical_table_types" value="MATERIALIZED VIEW"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="update" />
</properties>
```

**Model class:**

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table( name = "PESSOA" )
public class Pessoa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    @Column( name = "ID_PESSOA" )
    private Long id;

    @Column( name = "NOME" )
    private String nome;

    @Column( name = "NOME_SOCIAL" )
    private String nomeSocial;

    @Column( name = "CPF" )
    private String cpf;

}
```

I added several breakpoints and tested my application but the method onPostUpdate is never being called. My question is, am I missing any configuration?

Comment: What does your `Post` model class look like?

Comment: Added the class Pessoa to the question

Comment: Can you also post the test you are running? For something like this, its also nice to create [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).